# Binding with ngModel angular dialog close

Tags: angular

I have a project that I can edit with dialog angular, but the problem is when I open the edit dialog what is changed automatically shows me in my UI I want to change after I save because if I change and click cancel that stays changed.

Below you can find a code when I inject data and save.

What I change in dialog immediately overwrites changes, I want that after I save these will persist.

Here is the dialog when it will open for edit.

```
updateEntry(entry: Entry) {
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(UpdateDialogComponent, { minWidth: "400px", maxWidth: "600px" });
dialogRef.componentInstance.entry = entry;
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
if (result != null) {
 this.spinner.show();
this._dnsaasService.updateEntry(entry.domain_id, entry.id, entry).subscribe(res => {
  this.spinner.hide();
  this.toastr.success("Entry successfully updated");
  this.store.dispatch(new LoadDomainEntries(this.currentState.currentDomain));
},
  error => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      /** spinner ends after 5 seconds */
      this.spinner.hide();
    }, 1000);
  }

);

 }
});
 }
```

This is the template of edit dialog:

```
 <h1 mat-dialog-title>{{'DNS.Update entry' | translate }}</h1>
 <div mat-dialog-content fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
 <form name="updateEntryForm" #formControl="ngForm" fxLayout="column"  fxFlex="100">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Type</mat-label>
        <mat-select placeholder="type" [(ngModel)]="entry.type" [disabled]="true" name="type">
            <mat-option value="A">A</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="CNAME">CNAME</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Hostname</mat-label>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="entry.fqdn" [disabled]="true" name="hostname">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="entry.type == 'A'">
        <mat-label>{{'DNS.IP address' | translate }}</mat-label>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="entry.value" name="value" required [pattern]="valueForTypeAPattern"
            #uname="ngModel">
        <mat-error *ngIf="uname.errors?.pattern">
            {{'DNS.Value not valid' | translate }}
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="entry.type == 'CNAME'">
        <mat-label>FQDN cible</mat-label>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="entry.value" name="value" required [pattern]="valueForTypeCNAMEPattern"
            #uname="ngModel">
        <mat-error *ngIf="uname.errors?.pattern">
            {{'DNS.Value not valid' | translate }}
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>TTL</mat-label>
        <mat-select placeholder="ttl" [(ngModel)]="entry.ttl" name="ttl">
            <mat-option value="300">5 min</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="3600">{{'DNS.1 hour' | translate }}</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="86400">{{'DNS.1 day' | translate }}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
</div>
 <div mat-dialog-actions fxLayoutAlign="end center">
<button mat-button (click)="onCancelClick()">{{'DNS.Cancel' | translate }}</button>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" [mat-dialog-close]="formControl" [disabled]="formControl.invalid">{{'DNS.Update'
    | translate }}</button>
```

This is the TS file of edit dialog.

```
 updateEntry(entry: Entry) {
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(UpdateDialogComponent, { minWidth: "400px", maxWidth: "600px" });
dialogRef.componentInstance.entry = entry;
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  if (result != null) {
    this.spinner.show();
    this._dnsaasService.updateEntry(entry.domain_id, entry.id, entry).subscribe(res => {
      this.spinner.hide();
      this.toastr.success("Entry successfully updated");
      this.store.dispatch(new LoadDomainEntries(this.currentState.currentDomain));
    },
      error => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          /** spinner ends after 5 seconds */
          this.spinner.hide();
        }, 1000);
      }

    );

  }
});
  }
```

Please Help to resolve this problem .

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is happening because you are setting the reference of `entry` object to `dialogRef.componentInstance.entry`.**

```
dialogRef.componentInstance.entry = entry; // this line sets the reference
```

> So just change it to:

```
dialogRef.componentInstance.entry = { ...entry };
```

**OR**

```
dialogRef.componentInstance.entry = Object.assign(entry);
```

**OR**

If you are using `lodash` library then:

```
dialogRef.componentInstance.entry = _.cloneDeep(entry);
```

**Note:** Remember you have to set the value when you close the dialog with success.

Comment: thank you for your answer I made the change he does not modify the table but when I click on edit it changes the content either

Comment: how to set the value when i close a dialog ??

Comment: Yes, that's why I have mentioned a note in the answer. So for that, you have to pass value when you close the dialog and in the afterClosed method you have to set entry.

Comment: how to do it please ?

Comment: Please follow this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-dialog?file=app%2Fexample%2Fexample.component.ts

Comment: <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="entry">Ok</button> See  [mat-dialog-close]="entry". This will return entry object. And you will get it in the result of dialogRef.afterClosed(). Inside afterClosed assign it to entry like entry = result;

Comment: Thank you so muck that worked for me please i want to see my another problem if possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55179899/keep-filter-on-table-after-table-refresh-angular7

Answer (score 0):

In this line

`dialogRef.componentInstance.entry = entry;`

you are assigning the `entry` variable in your parent class to be referenced by the `entry` variable in your dialog class.

This means that the two are one and the same at the storage level, so edits in one model will "appear" in the "other" model.

The solution is to either copy the parent `entry` variable, or to use a different set of variables inside the dialog and return these to the parent on save.

Note that changing the variable name won't affect this, it is the `=` assignment.